# Getting 'undefined' for $event passed in nativescript events - IOS (N-Playground Test)

Tags: javascript, ios, events, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to create a 6x6 matrix of Labels in NativeScript, where user can able to drag(PAT) each label anywhere on PAT event.

Using Angular 8 version with NativeScript.

Here is the preview. 
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=gAm1KM&v=193

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/drag-and-drop-ui-elements-with-basic-collision-detection

[Dragging and Dropping in NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832339/dragging-and-dropping-in-nativescript)

https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/events

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/Calendar/event-handling

Tried almost all the resources but didnt worked.

When executed the code on IOS NativeScript app getting args as undefined.

HTML
`<Label text="ABC" (tap)="onTap($event)"></Label>`

TS
`onTap(args: EventData): void {
    console.log("On touch...", args);
}`

PREVIEW
On touch...undefined
On touch...undefined
On touch...undefined
On touch...undefined

Always $event is not passing to function.

`onTap(args: EventData): void {
    console.log("On touch...", args);
}`

Expecting args object when $event is passed when fired any of the nativescript event.

Comment: Are you sure you attached the right version of Playground, I don't see any issues on iOS neither Android.

Comment: Yes its the current version. When I open it on my iPhone 6S Plus, when I run the application I am getting undefined and app is closing automatically.

Comment: Try reinstalling your Playground and Preview apps, it worked for me on both iOS & Android.

Comment: @Manoj Thank you. It got worked with fresh installation of Playground app.